# C# how to avoid multiple foreach and if statements

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below function that works and cycles through 3 possible levels.
Is there a way to do the same as the function below but not have to do the multiple foreach statements?
Basically the reponses list can contain multiple GroupResponseTypes
each of these can contain multiple ElementResponseBaseTypes
which can be a variety of types themselves
I'm interested in finding a value in an ElementResponseType
And each ElementResponseBaseType itself can be a GroupResponseType, it to containing multiple types.

So i'm looking at an easy way to scan through the whole structure for a specific Element.Reference
and return the relevant value

Any help is much appreciated

```
public static string GetValueFromFormField(List<ResponseBaseType> responses, string fieldref)
{
    string fieldvalue = String.Empty;
    foreach (GroupResponseType groups in responses)
    {
        foreach (ElementResponseBaseType firstelements in groups.Responses)
        {
            if (firstelements.GetType() == typeof(ElementResponseType))
            {
                if (firstelements.Element.Reference == fieldref)
                {
                    ElementResponseType firstelement = new ElementResponseType();
                    firstelement = (ElementResponseType)firstelements;
                    fieldvalue = firstelement.Value;
                }
            }
            else if (firstelements.GetType() == typeof(GroupResponseType))
            {
                GroupResponseType secondgroup = new GroupResponseType();
                secondgroup = (GroupResponseType)firstelements;
                foreach (ElementResponseBaseType secondelements in secondgroup.Responses)
                {
                    if (secondelements.GetType() == typeof(ElementResponseType))
                    {
                        if (secondelements.Element.Reference == fieldref)
                        {
                            ElementResponseType secondelement = new ElementResponseType();
                            secondelement = (ElementResponseType)secondelements;
                            fieldvalue = secondelement.Value;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (secondelements.GetType() == typeof(GroupResponseType))
                    {
                        GroupResponseType thirdgroup = new GroupResponseType();
                        thirdgroup = (GroupResponseType)secondelements;
                        foreach (ElementResponseBaseType thirdelements in thirdgroup.Responses)
                        {
                            if (thirdelements.GetType() == typeof(ElementResponseType))
                            {
                                if (thirdelements.Element.Reference == fieldref)
                                {
                                    ElementResponseType thirdelement = new ElementResponseType();
                                    thirdelement = (ElementResponseType)thirdelements;
                                    fieldvalue = thirdelement.Value;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fieldvalue;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use LINQ to achieve cleaner looking filtering code?

Comment: You shouldn't be testing the type of each object and acting differently, you should be using polymorphism.  Each of the types should implement a common method based on their individual differences, allowing code using those types to be written without needing to know which of the derived types of the common interface a particular object is.

Comment: Hi, yes i tried using link in the first place but couldnt work out/make it iterate through the levels which could be n different levels of GroupResponseType

Comment: Adding to @Servy's comment: you might want to look at the [Composite design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk but this code has some other problems. Like creating a variable with assignment and discarding the value on the next line. Yes you can cut some lines of code by using `SelectMany` and other Linq methods. Process this code with ReSharper it will guide you until you see green bar.

Comment: To loop through all `GroupResponseTypes` I think you can use `SelectMany()` and `OfType()` methods to do so.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The code is currently not working, as it only works to a finite depth, rather than a depth not known at compile time.

Comment: This code has many problems.  Starting with why on earth are you using `x.GetType() == typeof(T)` instead of `x is T` ???

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify which parts of your code are used repeatedly and factor them out into new methods. If you do that over and over, eventually you will obtain something like this:

```
public static string GetValueFromResponses(IEnumerable<ElementResponseBaseType> responses, string fieldref)
{
    foreach (ElementResponseBaseType response in responses)
    {
        ElementResponseType element = response as ElementResponseType;
        if (element != null)
        {
            string foundValue = CheckElement(element, fieldref);
            if (foundValue != null)
            {
                return foundValue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GroupResponseType group = response as GroupResponseType;
            if (group != null)
            {
                string foundValue = GetValueFromResponses(group.Responses, fieldref);
                if (foundValue != null)
                {
                    return foundValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}

private static string CheckElement(ElementResponseType element, string fieldref)
{
    if (element.Element.Reference == fieldref)
    {
        return element.Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Here's a version that uses Linq (this contains all of the functionality in your original method):

```
public static string GetValueFromResponses(IEnumerable<ElementResponseBaseType> responses, string fieldref)
{
    var foundInElements = responses.OfType<ElementResponseType>()
                                   .Select(e => CheckElement(e, fieldref));
    var foundInGroups = responses.OfType<GroupResponseType>()
                                 .Select(g => GetValueFromResponses(g.Responses, 
                                                                    fieldref));

    return foundInElements.Concat(foundInGroups)
                          .FirstOrDefault(s => s != null) ?? string.Empty;
}

private static string CheckElement(ElementResponseType element, string fieldref)
{
    if (element.Element.Reference == fieldref)
    {
        return element.Value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi,yes this linq version is what I was after, its not quite the same though as my starting collection is List<ResponseBaseType> which is only the top level one, and if any of those are a GroupResponseType, the responses in that are ElementResponseBaseTypes.

Comment: What is your class hierarchy? Does `ElementResponseBaseType` inherit from `ResponseBaseType`, or is it the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

You should give your base type, in this case `ResponseBaseType`, a member that returns all of it's decedent leaf nodes.  You can then implement the behavior of that member separately for each type.  The group type can return all of the leaves in all of its own children (recursively), and the single item can return itself.

You can then take any instance of the base type and get all of the leaves, or, in this case, the first leaf.  Note that since you're only trying to get the first result here, not all of them, you'd benefit from making your implementation of the group's member use deferred execution, so that you don't need to bother computing all of the values just to get the first.

As complex as that might seem at first, it takes very little code to actually implement.

```
public abstract class ResponseBaseType
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<ElementResponseType> Leaves { get; }
}

public class GroupResponseType : ResponseBaseType
{
    public IEnumerable<ResponseBaseType> Children { get; private set; }
    public override IEnumerable<ElementResponseType> Leaves
    {
        get
        {
            return Children.SelectMany(child => child.Leaves);
        }
    }
}

public class ElementResponseType : ResponseBaseType
{
    public override IEnumerable<ElementResponseType> Leaves
    {
        get
        {
            yield return this;
        }
    }
}
```

This enables you to take your list of responses, map it to a sequences of all of their leaves, and then get the first/last leaf from that.

```
responses.SelectMany(response => response.Leaves).Last();
```